# How to achieve a hard edge at this geometrical intersection?

Tags: 3dsmax

[image]

Im trying to make this edge appear smooth, soo that the faces on each side seem to meet up smoothly. But I want the green edges around this to be hard and sharp. I am using 3ds max, and this is the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just apply a different smoothing group to the green polys

Comment: Hi Relidex I just tried what you suggested, and it seemed to be the same. I even turned on the hard edge display after and it calculated the same edges I did manually. Perhaps its a turbo smooth crease issue?a